# Why did HFPA put The Martian under comedy?

Tags: the-martian, awards

I am wondering why did [HFPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_Foreign_Press_Association) put The Martian under comedy? Is it because they wanted to give it an award? Has something similar happened before?

Comment: Well there are only two categories: *Drama* and *Comedy/Musical*... The Martian may not qualify as a pure comedy, but it most certainly is not a *Drama* in the traditional sense either...

Comment: Certainly funnier than *The Tourist*. Then again, what isn't?

Comment: With the recurring motif of "70s disco music" throughout - maybe it _really_ was a "Comedy/Musical"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Martian was classified as a Comedy by HFPA because the Hollywood Foreign Press Association’s eligibility committee voted to make it so. [According to the LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/envelope/goldstandard/la-et-mn-golden-globes-martian-joy-trumbo-20151112-column.html) the HFPA vote was very close as The Martian ended up classified as a comedy by just one vote.

Without specific comments from those who voted it would be nothing more than speculation to discuss the "why" however it's worth noting that the Golden Globes comedy category is the weaker of the two categories it awards and this isn't the first time a movie has been classified as a comedy at the Golden Globes.